# matplotlib plot() error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am enconterring a problem when trying to plot graphs using plot() with matplottlib.

Here is a snippet of the code that codes the exception, along with the exception stacktrace and error messages:

```
def line_graph(p_collection, filename, *args, **kwargs):
    def plot(top):
        temp = [p.foo_bar for p in p_collection]
        print temp
        top.plot(temp, '-', label="foobar") # <- This is line 801
    multi_graph(p_collection, filename, plot, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Output:**

```
[276.25, 274.0, 257.0, 261.0, 259.75, 256.5, 261.0, 263.75, 257.5, 260.0, 251.0, 247.5, 246.0, 243.0, 243.75, 247.0, 244.0, 246.75, 251.0, 247.75, 245.75, 241.0, 251.0, 258.0, 258.75, 257.0, 262.0, 263.0, 256.0, 260.0, 261.0, 267.0, 264.25, 261.0, 268.5, 266.0, 268.25, 268.0, 271.0, 263.5, 259.0, 262.5, 265.5, 260.0, 261.5, 258.75, 258.25, 258.5, 255.0, 255.25, 251.75, 250.25, 256.5, 248.75, 249.5, 248.25, 246.0, 248.0, 248.5, 251.0, 254.5, 249.5, 248.5, 251.0, 253.0, 258.0, 259.0, 260.0, 262.0, 269.5, 259.25, 258.0, 250.5, 250.5, 250.5, 258.25, 255.5, 247.25, 248.0, 243.0, 247.5, 248.0, 251.25, 256.0, 250.0, 245.0, 241.5, 240.25, 247.5, 247.5, 246.0, 247.0, 250.0, 243.5, 235.5, 241.5, 249.5, 243.0, 243.5, 245.25]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotfuncs.py", line 1080, in <module>
    unit_test()
  File "plotfuncs.py", line 1072, in unit_test
    left_view=(0, 40),
  File "plotfuncs.py", line 802, in line_graph
    multi_graph(phist, filename, plot, *args, **kwargs)
  File "plotfuncs.py", line 594, in multi_graph
    plot(top)
  File "plotfuncs.py", line 801, in plot
    top.plot(temp, '-', label="foobar")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3853, in plot
    self.autoscale_view(scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1842, in autoscale_view
    x0, x1 = xlocator.view_limits(x0, x1)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I don't understand the internal workings of matplotlib - BUT as can be seen from the output data passed to the plot() function, there are no None types, so I don't understand why a NoneType is being encountered durther down the call stack when the data is being iterated over - can someone please explain?

Comment: I assume `top` is an `Axis`. What has been done to `top` before calling its plot member in line 801?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `xlocator.view_limits(x0, x1)` is None, so it can't iterate to expand the output to `x0, x1`.  I don't know why this is though.  I notice that the error happens in a unit_test function, presumably matlibplot's unit tests.  If that is raising an error, it looks like one of matlibplot's unit tests are failing, so perhaps you should report it.

Comment: Sorry - don't know how I misread that!  I'll update the answer.